# Receiving Invalid Argument in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I've been staring at this for hours and could really use some help. I'm working with some existing code for a movie theater website and the following should fill a select list with dates ranging from today to a max date from an xml file.

```
function populateSelect(xmlDoc, elSel) {
    var dmindate = new Date();
    var showings = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Session');
    fmaxdate = "";
    for (var showing = 0; showing < showings.length; showing++) {
        if (retText(showings[showing].getElementsByTagName('Date_time')[0]) > fmaxdate) {
            fmaxdate=retText(showings[showing].getElementsByTagName('Date_time')[0]);//get the Max Date
        }
    }

    var dmaxdate = new Date.parseString(fmaxdate, "yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    while(dmindate <= dmaxdate){ //Fill in the Select List
        var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
        elOptNew.text = dmindate.format("EE NNN d, yyyy");
        elOptNew.value = dmindate.format("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dmindate.setDate(dmindate.getDate()+1);
        try {
            elSel.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant doesn't work in IE
        }
        catch(ex) {
            elSel.add(elOptNew); // IE only
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine in FF, Chrome and Safari but IE8 doesn't display the dropdown with dates and it showed the Invalid Argument as being the same line as the closing bracket for try.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Given this is tagged "jquery", why are you manually creating elements with `document.createElement()`? Wouldn't it be easier to use jQuery methods for this, and let jQuery worry about cross-browser compatibility?

Comment: But I didn't see any code like jQuery in the given example.

Comment: Sorry about that. Labeled it incorrectly. Still very new to this.

Comment: What line do you receive Invalid Argument error?

Comment: try {
            elSel.add(elOptNew, null); // standards compliant doesn't work in IE
        } <---- Right here at this line.

Comment: Can't tell by the way my comment was formatted but the arrow is pointing to the line that just has the closing bracket right after elSel.add(elOptNew, null);

Comment: @user1606025–IE **is** standards compliant in that regard. If the object passed as the second argument isn't a descendant of the element being appended to, an error should be thrown (i.e. the OP shouldn't be passing `null`). See the [DOM 2 HTML add](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-14493106) method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where `Date.prototype.parseString` or `format` methods come from, presumably you are adding some date library. They aren't part of ECMAScript ed 3 or 5.

You can replace these lines:

```
> var elOptNew = document.createElement('option'); 
> elOptNew.text =dmindate.format("EE NNN d, yyyy");
> elOptNew.value = dmindate.format("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

with:

```
var elOptNew = new Option(dmindate.format("EE NNN d, yyyy"), // option text
                          dmindate.format("MM/dd/yyyy"));    // option value
```

then add it to the select:

```
elSel.appendChild(elOptNew);
```

The above will work in all versions of IE and other browsers. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-option-element for details of the Option constructor.

#### Edit

In the DOM 2 HTML specification for the [add method](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-14493106) it says:

> This method is the equivalent of the appendChild method of the Node
>   interface if the before parameter is null.

That doesn't mean to pass the ECMAScript `null` object, it means "if there is no second parameter". The specification is language neutral, it isn't javascript specific. The HTML5 OptionsCollection [add method](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#dom-htmloptionscollection-add) is the same (i.e. "null" means no parameter, not the javascript `null` object).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation I could find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), having a null parameter doesn't make any sense. However, it is clear that the JavaScript engines in the different browsers handle this method differently, and that IE doesn't like `null` as the second parameter.

So, as per the mantra, [you should use jQuery. It is good and does all things.](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) It does actually help protect you from differences between browser implementations of the DOM, because it has a [fairly broad compatibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).  It fixed [this guy's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231543/javascript-error-in-add-method-using-ie8) anyway.

You will probably want to use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of the `add()`. For example:

```
var elOptNew = $('<option></option>');
...
elSel.append(elOptNew);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your suggestion above but it stopped the dates from loading in the dropdown, leaving it blank in all browsers. It also gave me an error in IE8 that "object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: I didn't give a complete example, so if you just stuck that line of code in I'm not surprised it didn't work. I could probably give you a more complete example, but I think RobG has answered your question now anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
elSel.options.add(elOptNew)
```

This must work in all browsers. [**See example**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is also an alternative way to add new options in to a select, i.e

```
var opts = elSel.options;
opts[opts.length] = new Option(dmindate.format("EE NNN d, yyyy"), dmindate.format("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

[**Example that works in all mejor browsers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000657/receiving-invalid-argument-in-ie8#12001087).