# javascript not working on ie8 -type mismatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

JavaScript not working on IE8 -getting type mismatch 
on this particular line:

```
from_s.add(temp, from_s.options[0]);
```

I have run this search/display code on Firefox and higher version of ie's and it
worked perfectly fine. I just don't get it, =(( i really really need this
one to work, I hope someone out there could help me =(

Here is my code that searches for a keyword and puts it on top
of the list:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function searchstudent(){
    var searchvalue= document.getElementById('search').value;
    var from_s = document.getElementById('students-out');
    for (var i=0;i<from_s.options.length-1;i++){
      var st = from_s.options[i].text;
      if(st.search(searchvalue)>-1){
        var temp = from_s.options[i];
        from_s.add(temp, from_s.options[0]);
      }
   }
 }
```

and the form:

```
<form id="search2">
  <input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="searchstudent()" placeholder="Enter Keyword here.. ." /><br/><br/><br/>
  <select name="users-out" id="students-out" multiple="multiple" size="10" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="n.html" title="ppp">ppp</option>
    <option value="n.html" title="ppp">yyy</option>
    <option value="g.html" title="qwe">qwe</option>
    <option value="32" title="bond desk">bond desk</option>
    <option value="32" title="qqq">qqq</option>
    <option value="26" title="     ">     </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `add()` [does not exist on `HTMLSelectElement` in IE8.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869732(v=vs.85).aspx)

Instead you could probably use the much more consistent and standardized [`insertBefore()` DOM Node method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

```
from_s.insertBefore(temp, from_s.options[0]);
```

Or `appendChild()` if you want it at the end.

See also: [JavaScript Error in add method using IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231543/javascript-error-in-add-method-using-ie8)

Comment: IE 7 and 8 support the *add* method on select elements.